# Error while building project hololens - Error: CS0006 "...\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" can not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, hololens

I'm building a simple project for Hololens.

Unique scene with a simple Cube.

I follow this tutorials for make it:

-> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms_100 
-> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using_visual_studio#hololens 
-> http://pterneas.com/2016/04/04/getting-started-hololens-unity3d/

But this erros is display when I build: [image]

I'm using the lastest version of Unity and Visual Studio:

Unity: **v2017.1.0f3** 
Visual Studio: **v15.3.2**

The interesting thing is I've a friend with **v15.2 release(26430.16)** Visual Studio and he is build any Hololens application normally.

I already re-install my Visual Studio and Unity (for lastest version) but the erros continues.

I found this tutorial -> http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/2017/06/24/hololens-fix-visual-studio-2017-build-error/ but not  works.

My output:

```
Restoring NuGet packages ...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during compilation, open the Visual Studio Options dialog box, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during compilation'.
1> ------ Compilation started: Project: Assembly-CSharp-firstpass, Configuration: x86 Release ------
1> Running SerializationWeaver ...
1> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The supplied key was not present in the dictionary.
1> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException ()
1> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item (TKey key)
1> in UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.NuGetPackageResolver.Resolve ()
1> in Unity.NuGetAssemblyResolver..ctor (String projectLockFile)
1> in usw.Weaver.ReaderParameters (String assemblyPath, ConversionOptions options)
1> in usw.Weaver.Weave ()
1> in usw.Program.RunProgram (ConversionOptions options)
1> in usw.Program.Main (String [] args)
C: \ Users \ luq.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp-firstpass \ Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.csproj (196,5): error MSB3073: : \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ Unity \ Tools \ SerializationWeaver \ SerializationWeaver.exe "" C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly- CSharp-firstpass \ bin \ x86 \ Release \ Unprocessed \ Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll "-pdb" -verbose "-web-engine = C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ BuildLimpa \ Unprocessed \ UnityEngine.dll "" C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ app \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp-FirstPass \ obj \ x86 \ Release \ x86 \ Release "" -lock = C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ app \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp-FirstPass \ project.lock.json "" @C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp-firstpass \ SerializationWeaverArgs.txt "-additionalAssemblyP ATH = C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ app \ BuildLimpa \ Unprocessed "" -unity-networking = C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ app \ BuildLimpa \ Unprocessed \ UnityEngine.Networking.dll "was terminated with code 1.
2> ------ Compilation started: Project: Assembly-CSharp, Configuration: Release x86 ------
2> CSC: error CS0006: C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp-firstpass \ bin \ x86 \ Release-Assembly-CSharp-firstpass source file. Dll "can not be found
3> ------ Compilation started: Project: BuildLimpa, Configuration: Release x86 ------
3> CSC: error CS0006: C: \ Users \ luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp-firstpass \ bin \ x86 \ Release-Assembly-CSharp-firstpass source file. Dll "can not be found
CSC: Error CS0006: C: \ Users \ Luiz.santana \ Documents \ _Unity3D \ BuildLimpa \ App \ GeneratedProjects \ UWP \ Assembly-CSharp \ bin \ x86 \ Release \ Assembly-CSharp.dll "source file can not To be found
========== Compile: 0 successfully, 3 failed, 0 refreshed, 0 ignored ==========
========== Deployment: 0 Successfully, 0 Failed, 0 Ignored ==========
```

What must be happening? How I can solve it?

---

#### Solved

I just changed the version in `project.lock.json` file. It was with `Version=v10.0.10240´. I just ´find/replace` all and replace for `Version=v10.0` and works!

I found a solution in this link: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/net-scripting-backend-and-visual-studio-2017-3-incompatibility.487833/

Comment: I would recommend you to check https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity. I would follow their version of getting started and keep up with releases. The toolkit contains lots of useful codes that you will definitely need.

Comment: You saved my life, thanks a lot.